# Codeigniter query within foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, query-optimization

I am trying to write PHP MVC for area wise message blocking. Like user check's the area checkbox from where they want's to get messages while uncheck the area checkbox from where they dont want to get message. Details of this checkbox option of a user is store in "geo" table with user_id and area code like in_p1,in_p2,... upto in_p17. e.g. in_p1 field in db should be 1 for a user if he want's messages from that particular area otherwise in_p1 should 0 to avoid messages from that area , same logic for area in_p2 tp in_p17. 
   In another table 'individu' table "in_pays" is area id from 1 to 17.My current MVC code working fine on local host but on live site as db has has more 5 millions of user for each area it's not working. 
so can you guy's help me out to avoid the query within foreach loop so that I can avoid the running of query millions of time? MY MVC code is as

**My Controller is**

```
$geo_arr=$this->settingmodel->get_geotable();
 //echo '<br><pre>'; print_r($geo_arr); echo '</pre>';
foreach($geo_arr as $geo)
{
   for($count=1;$count<18;$count++)
   {    
      $in_p='in_p'.$count; //in_p1,in_p2..in_p17 is column name in `geo` table
      if($geo->$in_p==1)   // e.g. if in_p1=1 then messages from area code 1 is allowed
      { 
        $this->settingmodel->unblock_messages($in_pays=$count);
      }
      else                //e.g. if in_p1!=1 then messages from area code 1 is not allowed
      {
    $this->settingmodel->block_message($in_pays=$count);
      }
   }
}
```

**My Model**

```
function unblock_messages($in_pays)
{
   $login_user=$this->session->userdata('in_pseudo');
   $this->db->select('in_pseudo');
   $this->db->from('individu');
   $this->db->where('in_pays',$in_pays);
   $query=$this->db->get();

   $result=$query->result();

   foreach($result as $res)
   {
      $me_from=$res->in_pseudo;
      $arr=array('ME_VALID'=>'NULL');
      $this->db->where('ME_FROM',$me_from);
      $this->db->where('ME_TO',$login_user);
      $this->db->update('message',$arr);

   }
}
function block_message($in_pays)
{

    $login_user=$this->session->userdata('in_pseudo');
    $this->db->select('in_pseudo');
    $this->db->from('individu');
    $this->db->where('in_pays',$in_pays);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $result=$query->result();

    foreach($result as $res)
    {
         $me_from=$res->in_pseudo;
         $arr=array('ME_VALID'=>'X');
         $this->db->where('ME_FROM',$me_from);
         $this->db->where('ME_TO',$login_user);
         $this->db->update('message',$arr);

    }
}

function get_geotable()
{
    $in_num=$this->session->userdata('in_num');
           $this->db->select('in_p1,in_p2,in_p3,in_p4,in_p5,in_p6,in_p7,in_p8,in_p9,in_p10,in_p11,in_p12,in_p13,in_p14,in_p15,in_p16,in_p17');

$this->db->from('geo');
    $this->db->where('in_num',$in_num);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $result=$query->result();
    return $result;
```

}

Comment: for this amount of data changes i would suggest you to use insert_batch() and update_batch() http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: use update_batch as @KURN said and also please make clear your question its a little bit confusing maybe you sould provide the database and good example

Comment: Since it is just database related operations, I think that is better to do a single SQL query to update your tables. Try to use SQL Procedures to solve it. Is not a good idea to do a lot of queries to database in a for loop. Every query uses a lot of system resources and take some time to be executed.